# Creating docker file which installs python with sklearn and pandas that can be used on sagemaker

Tags: docker, amazon-sagemaker

I am quite new to docker. My problem in short is to create a docker file that contains python with sklearn and pandas which can be used on aws sagemaker.

My current docker file looks like the following:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

RUN pip3 install sagemaker-training

COPY train.py /opt/ml/code/train.py

ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py
```

However when i try to create this image I get an error at line `pip3 install sagemaker-training`. The error is the following:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/conda/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fj0cb373/sagemaker-training_66ca9935ed134c95ac11a32e118e4568/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fj0cb373/sagemaker-training_66ca9935ed134c95ac11a32e118e4568/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-o5rzjscd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/conda/include/python3.9/sagemaker-training Check the logs for full command output.

The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c pip3 install sagemaker-training' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If there is a more suitable base image can someone point that out to me? I am generally trying to follow this page https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit.

Note: I realise I can use some sagemaker pre-built containers without using my own docker file. However I am trying to do this for my own learning so I know what to do for projects that can't utilise them.

Comment: Do the docker logs provide additional output about the failed command with a non-zero exit code? Is it possible that `pip3` isn't installed in the base image `jupyter/scipy-notebook`?

Comment: I have added more of the errors in the question if that helps

Comment: Is there any additional command output above the `ERROR` log that you added to the question?

Comment: Yes there is. I have just updated the question

Comment: It looks like the base image that you are using does not have `gcc` installed which is required in order to install `sagemaker-training`. Try adding the following above the line that installs `sagemaker-training` in your Dockerfile:

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted your Dockerfile and it builds successfully for me.

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
ARG defaultuser=jovyan
USER root
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER $defaultuser

RUN pip3 install sagemaker-training

COPY train.py /opt/ml/code/train.py

ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py
```

(I had to adjust for the fact that the default user from the base container isn't root, when installing GCC)